# How to align a span and a div on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="mega_parent">
<div class="parent">
<div class="holder">
    <span class="holder_under">Left heading</span>
    <div class="holder_options">
        <span class="holder_options_1">Option 1</span> 
        <span class="holder_options_2">Option 2</span> 
        <span class="holder_options_3">Option 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.holder {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
.holder_under {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #999;
}
.parent {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 600px;
}
 .mega_parent {
background-color: blue;
    margin: 130px auto;
    min-height: 320px;
    height: 100% auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 940px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

**Question:**

How do I make the div with the class `holder_options` align in the same line as the span with the class `.holder_under`?

Here's what it looks like currently in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QELyG/3/).

Comment: `float: left` should help

Comment: You could start by ending your divs properly.

Comment: Your `Option 2` span is unclosed. **Edit:** Or was, until @LenialMacaferi edited it for you. Check your code to ensure that the span is closed.

Comment: you are lucky.8 answers already .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Div's are by default **block** level elements. Please read up more about [**block level elements here.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> "Block level elements - Their most significant characteristic is that they typically are
>   formatted with a line break before and after the element (thereby
>   creating a stand-alone block of content)."

Set it to `display:inline-block;`

```
.holder_options {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QELyG/1/)

Comment: Thanks Zenith.  I apologize, I forgot one div that was in that code.  Can you please review it one more time if it's not too much? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again but it doesn't seem to move up and align on my code.  NOt sure what's going wrong there!

Comment: @starbucks I don't understand? It works just fine for the code you've given?

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  I going to take a look at my stuff again.

Comment: Hey, I checked my code and looks OK for some reason I can't get it work using your fix.  I am sure it's simple and your fiddle seems right too so not sure what's wrong. I will take another look.

Comment: Thanks again for helping @zenith.  i updated the question and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgKuU/

Comment: @starbucks I don't understand the problem? My code works perfectly there too - http://jsfiddle.net/jgKuU/1/. Please remember to accept my answer, thanks starbucks.

Comment: @starbucks My code works just fine there too of course - http://jsfiddle.net/jgKuU/1/. Please remember to accept my answer for spending the time to help you, thanks man. :)

Comment: it didn't work on mine but I accepted it anyway since it works on your fiddle.  Can you help me out later if I continue to have this problem? Thanks!

Comment: @starbucks Sure thing. I can help in a few hours when I finish work. If the problem is different, ask a new question and link me. If not, post me a link here to your source code and I'll look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

by default div's are `display:block` which is set to take 100% of the width. set it to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` to take only what it needs and allow others to fit on the same line

Answer (score 1):

u need **inline-block**

This is where the magic value inline-block for the display property comes into play. Basically, it’s a way to make elements inline, but preserving their block capabilities such as setting width and height, top and bottom margins and paddings etc

css

```
.holder {
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .holder_under {
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #999;
    }
    .holder_options {
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

html

```
 <div class="holder">
      <span class="holder_under">Left heading</span>
          <div class="holder_options">
              <span class="holder_options_1">Option 1</span> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.holder_options
{
  float:right;
}
```

Here's the JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/idilim/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes the structure you have laid out is not done well however, just float .holder_options to the left:

```
.holder_options {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Morpheus stated in a comment, `style="display: inline;"` should do it.

```
<div class="holder">
    <span class="holder_under">Left heading</span>
    <div class="holder_options" style="display: inline;">
        <span class="holder_options_1">Option 1</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```